# How to interpolate a curve with irregular scale?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, spline, smoothing

I have the following granulometric data that I want to show on a graph, where x is the grain size and y, the probability density function. x follows a geometric sequence (each value multiplied by 2)

x: [0.0, 0.078130000000000005, 0.15626000000000001, 0.31252000000000002, 0.62504000000000004, 1.2500800000000001, 2.5001600000000002, 5.0003200000000003, 10.000640000000001, 20.001280000000001]

y:  [0.0, 1.0512499897262986, 0.8764973224043381, 0.6221799472771921, 0.3760124741123981, 0.19346808043817057, 0.08474951460350254, 0.0316071940839253, 0.010035880788326037, 0.0]

Here is the graph:

[image]

I've been trying to smooth the curve like Excel does. I've tried using interp1d (all methods), spline, Akima1DInterpolator.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: use a semi-log fit?

Comment: "Nothing seems to work" is a bit broad, what exactly does not work?

Comment: `x` has 9, `y` has 10 elements, so this will definitively fail. Moreover, if you really put the zero in the beginning, you have a super sharp transition in the beginning, which will result in ugly interpolation in all mentioned methods. (I guess the starting zero is wrong though, removing this should result in something to interpolate easily)

Comment: Thank you, indeed I had forgotten the 0 for x!  I interpolated without the zeros, then added it manually and it worked better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my comment above I said *easily*. The problem, however, is the fact that the data is very flat at the end. Cubic and higher order interpolation do not like flat data. They tend to *oscillate*. The trick would be, as mentioned by @f5r5e5d, to rescale the data in such a way that the flat part becomes very short. In this case a double-log-scale seems OK. Unfortunately, this does not work with `y = 0` values. Hence, either one has to remove this value or choose a reasonable small value for it (but not too small as on a double-log-scale that point would drift off).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

xList = [0.078130000000000005, 0.15626000000000001, 0.31252000000000002, 0.62504000000000004, 1.2500800000000001, 2.5001600000000002, 5.0003200000000003, 10.000640000000001, 20.001280000000001]

yList = [ 1.0512499897262986, 0.8764973224043381, 0.6221799472771921, 0.3760124741123981, 0.19346808043817057, 0.08474951460350254, 0.0316071940839253, 0.010035880788326037, 0.0]

yList[-1] = 1.e-5 ###manually put a value for the zero

xLogList = [ np.log( x ) for x in xList ]
yLogList = [ np.log( y ) for y in yList ]
f = interp1d(xLogList, yLogList, kind='cubic')
xInterLogList = np.linspace( np.log( xList[0] ), np.log( xList[-1] ), 100 )
yInterLogList = [ f( x ) for x in xInterLogList ]

fig1=plt.figure()
ax=fig1.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

ax.plot(xList, yList)
ax.plot( [ np.exp( x ) for x in xInterLogList  ], [ np.exp( y ) for y in yInterLogList ] )

plt.show()
```

[image: Interpolation]
In blue the original data, in orange the *smooth* interpolation.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, I've tried it and it worked!